Getting my IDE to show autocompletion for only generic typ specified in interface (using MediatR, C#)
I want to ensure that my IDE, during autocomplete for function parameters, suggests only (or at least prioritizes) the parameters that are allowed in the function. Specifically, this pertains to an extension function for the MediatR library.
The following example illustrates the problem:

using MediatR;

namespace ITaskTest;

public class Result<T> {
    public T Value { get; set; }
    public string ErrorMessage { get; set; } 
}

public class Result { }


public interface ITask : IRequest<Result>;

public interface ITask<TResponse> : IRequest<Result<TResponse>>;


public record TestTask : ITask;

public record TestTaskGeneric : ITask<TestTaskGenericResponse>;
public record TestTaskGenericResponse(string Message);


public static class MediatorExtensions
{
    public static async Task<Result> RunTask(this IMediator mediator, ITask task) {
        return await mediator.Send(task);
    }

    public static async Task<Result<TResponse>> RunTaskGeneric<TResponse>(this IMediator mediator, ITask<TResponse> task) {
        return await mediator.Send(task);
    }
}

public class Class1
{
    private readonly IMediator mediator;

    public Class1(IMediator mediator) {
        this.mediator = mediator;
    }

    public async Task Test() {
        // IDE should suggest TestTask here -> does work!
        var result = await mediator.RunTask(new TestTask());

        // IDE should suggest TestTaskGeneric here -> does not work!
        var resultGeneric = await mediator.RunTaskGeneric(new TestTaskGeneric());
    }
}

Also see images for example.
does work
does not work
The reason why this makes sense: I have a large number of ITask implementations as well as some other interfaces like IQuery and ICommand. During development, I want to limit the selection of options. Additionally, it doesn't make sense for options like TestTaskGenericResponse to be suggested as a possible parameter. The IDE even immediately points out that it’s not a valid parameter but still suggests it.
Am I missing something here? Or is something like this generally not possible?
I’ve tried various configurations and asked ChatGPT multiple times, but I haven’t been able to find a solution.

— Please, don't post pictures with textual information instead of text, such as code, error messages, exception information or the like. Please always provide textual information. Pictures are fine, but not for this purpose. Don't you think people will perform OCR on your images? Hardly.

Sorry, I’m not exactly sure what you mean. The images show how my IDE (Rider) is currently behaving. How can I provide a visual example from my IDE without using an image?

— please see https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask. Pictures are fine, but the pictures you show contain essential textual information. You know, nobody would care about the layout and colors of this text, you need to provide the text itself, even if you provide pictures. And you could easily do it.
